# Copying information over when there are multiple datapoints

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, recode

I have a data cleaning question. The data collection happened three times and sometimes the data entry was incorrect. Therefore, if the students had their data collected more than one time, the `second` data point needs to be copied over.

Here is my dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,  4,4, 5),
                 text = c("female","male","male", "female","female","female", "male","female","male", "female", "female"),
                 time = c("first","second","third", "first","second","third", "first","second","second", "third", "first"))
            
> df
   id   text   time
1   1 female  first
2   1   male second
3   1   male  third
4   2 female  first
5   2 female second
6   2 female  third
7   3   male  first
8   3 female second
9   4   male second
10  4 female  third
11  5 female  first
```

So `id` 1,3, and 4 have incorrect gender information. I need to copy the `second` data point when there are multiple/different input about the `gender` variable. If there is only one datapoint, that should stay in the dataset.

The desired output would be

```
> df1
   id   text   time
1   1   male  first
2   1   male second
3   1   male  third
4   2 female  first
5   2 female second
6   2 female  third
7   3 female  first
8   3 female second
9   4   male second
10  4   male  third
11  5 female  first
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(text = text[match("second", time, nomatch = 1)]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 3
      id text   time  
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
 1     1 male   first 
 2     1 male   second
 3     1 male   third 
 4     2 female first 
 5     2 female second
 6     2 female third 
 7     3 female first 
 8     3 female second
 9     4 male   second
10     4 male   third 
11     5 female first
```

---

Or using `coalesce`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(text = coalesce(text[match("second", time)], text)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 3
      id text   time  
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
 1     1 male   first 
 2     1 male   second
 3     1 male   third 
 4     2 female first 
 5     2 female second
 6     2 female third 
 7     3 female first 
 8     3 female second
 9     4 male   second
10     4 male   third 
11     5 female first
```

Comment: hi @akrun I have a open question. Do you have time to take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790880/data-cleaning-question-read-from-excel-files-in-r

Comment: little challenging. yes.

Comment: just fixed that part, needed to exclude birthday information.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for any part of that question? Thanks for your time!

Comment: now I split it into three parts. thanks for the suggestion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73802817/data-cleaning-question-read-from-excel-files-in-r-1

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach for the fun of it;

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(time =="second") %>% 
  select(-time) %>% 
  full_join(df, ., by ="id", suffix = c("_old", "")) %>% 
  mutate(text = coalesce(text, text_old)) %>% 
  select(names(df))

#>       id text   time  
#>  1     1 male   first 
#>  2     1 male   second
#>  3     1 male   third 
#>  4     2 female first 
#>  5     2 female second
#>  6     2 female third 
#>  7     3 female first 
#>  8     3 female second
#>  9     4 male   second
#> 10     4 male   third 
#> 11     5 female first
```

Answer (score 1):

With {dplyr} we can use the following approach:

1. we `group_by(id)`
2. check in `ifelse` if there is an element in `text` when `time == "second"` and to do this we use `length`
3. if thats the case use `text[time == "second"]` otherwise use `text`

I just wonder, what should happen if you have three data entires and `first` and `second` are the same and `third` is different. Then the approach above won't work.

Also what should happen if `first` is `"male"`, `second` is `"female"` and `third` is again `"male"`. Which one should be taken?

The approach below just uses `second` if its available and ignores the rest.

```r
library(dplyr)


df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(text = ifelse(length(text[time == "second"]) > 0,
                       text[time == "second"],
                       text))

#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>       id text   time  
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1     1 male   first 
#>  2     1 male   second
#>  3     1 male   third 
#>  4     2 female first 
#>  5     2 female second
#>  6     2 female third 
#>  7     3 female first 
#>  8     3 female second
#>  9     4 male   second
#> 10     4 male   third 
#> 11     5 female first
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>